# Lista de Checkbox selecionados só contém os que estão na tela

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Tenho um `GridView` que contém uma lista de items com um `checkbox` e faço uso do código abaixo para "paginar" a tabela:

```
$(".gvdatatable").dataTable();
```

O problema ocorre quando vou verificar quais os `checkboxes`estão selecionados, pois neste momento só é listado àqueles que estão sendo exibidos na tela, ou seja, se eu selecionar dois itens da página 1 e selecionar um item na página 2, o código só considera o `checkbox` selecionado da página 2. O interessante é que se volto para a página 1 o `checkbox` continua selecionado. Código do `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataTables" CssClass="gvdatatable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover textTable" runat="server"
                                AutoPostBack="True"
                                OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound"
                                OnPreRender="dataTables_PreRender">

<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckTodos" runat="server" onclick="GridSelectAllColumn(this);"/>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckStatus" runat="server" CssClass="chk" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="NOME" HeaderText="NOME"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CPF" HeaderText="CPF" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DATANASCIMENTO" HeaderText="DATA NASCIMENTO" />

</Columns>
```

Códido que recupera os `checkbox`:

```
foreach (GridViewRow viewRow in dataTables.Rows)
{
     var t = viewRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckStatus") as CheckBox;

     if (t.Checked)
     {
        lista.Add(t);
     }
}
```